# Outlook rename attachments and save to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script that I found that currently saves attachments but I also need it to rename those attachments to the same name.

For a little background I am creating a system that updates inventory on one of my websites. To do this I get a report(CSV) from our ERP with all my item numbers and inventory counts.

They are emailed to me but the attached CSV always has a name that ends in a different number.

I need the file to have the same name every time because the script I have saves that CSV to a folder and I have a FTP program that auto FTPs that CSV to my web server.

From here I have a PHP script on a cron job that runs through the CSV and updates the quantity on my products.

Believe me, if my ERP had an API this would be so much easier but no luck on that.

Anyhow, my issue lies in the naming of the attachment. The script below saves it but I need it to also strip the numbers from the name or just name it to 'CPNINVTRUM'.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
     Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
     Dim saveFolder As String
     saveFolder = "C:\PATH"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
     objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
     Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

The attachment is always in this form: CPNINVTRUM###.csv. The ### signifies the the 3 digit random number that is generated by the ERP.

Comment: Please give examples of the current attachment names.

Comment: They are all like this CPNINVTRUM###.CSV. The ### at the end is always a 3 digit number.

Comment: How can you save multiple attachments to a file with the same name? The file would be overwritten. And if you don't care about that, the SaveAsFile line should be objAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\PATH\CPNINVTRUM"

Comment: I don't care. The FTP program I use moves the file once it uploads it and on top of that I have a rule in Outlook to only run this script if the subject includes something specific. I think I have everything covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the save line to

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\CPNINVTRUM.csv"
```