# Saving and renaming an Outlook attachment with static name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code which saves an attachment to a specific place and renames it to "name.xls"

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:\Users\acheng\Desktop"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\name.xls"
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

A user did something very similar in this thread with .csv files:

[VBA Outlook - Rename attachments and save to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244636/vba-outlook-rename-attachments-and-save-to-folder)

I did the same thing, except with a .xls file.

My script saves and renames the file, but when I try to open the file it says: "'name.xls' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that it is not corrupt..."

Once I hit Yes and it opens, all the data is in weird symbols.  If I replace & '\name.xls' with '& objAtt.DisplayName' it will properly save the file with it's original name.

I have double checked that this is a .xls file. Figuring out something more universal (so that the same script works for .xls .xlsx and .xlsm) would also be hugely helpful, but not as big a priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is more than one attachment, your code might replace the Excel attachment with one of the other attachments.

Try something like this, to find out

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
     Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
     Dim saveFolder As String
     Dim i as Integer

     i=0
     saveFolder = "C:\Users\acheng\Desktop"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          i = i + 1
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\name" & i & ".xls"
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

You should add some validation here. Assuming that all attachments are Excel files is a big risk.

Comment: This worked!  The issue was that while I assumed the email only had 1 attachment, the senders email signature had a small picture in it.  The script was saving the attachment as name.xls first, then overwriting it with the picture second.  What do you mean by validation and how would you filter it in such a way that it only downloaded excel file attachments?

Comment: @user7926636 Use case select to save only specific file type see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43180639/4539709