# How to download, rename and save excel and pdf files using python from gmail

Tags: python, vba, excel, pdf

As the title states, I need to download attachments from gmail that are in excel and pdf format and rename them based on a cell in excel (A2). I understand pdfs might be a little different so let's focus on excel only unless there is an easy way around it. I made sure my gmail account has imap enabled. This is the first time I'm running python. If you think VBA might be easier, please let me know!

Basically, there's a 3rd party software that we use to download reports. We're able to send those reports automatically to a central gmail account which then needs to be downloaded into a folder, by month. The emails we receive in that gmail account have many attachments since each reports is a separate email. Would this be possible to download?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to find this: https://gist.github.com/baali/2633554

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why your question was downvoted - isn't Stackoverflow a platform for users to seek answers? Many of us just need someone else to point us in the right direction, it doesn't mean that we are spoonfeeding them with the answers.

I have used Excel VBA extensively to carry out similar tasks and I would suggest that you use Microsoft Outlook (as in the desktop application which is part of Microsoft Office) to search through the emails easier for you. Log in to your email account from Outlook, and in Excel VBA, import the Microsoft Outlook reference.

You can then loop through all your mail items and their respective attachments, and if the file extension is pdf or excel, download them and rename accordingly.

The following links might help you get a rough idea of how to carry this project out:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68409524-9b5e-4ac4-aeb8-f595dff31260/in-outlook-how-can-i-use-vba-to-search-through-xls-attachments-in-my-inbox-for-specific-values?forum=isvvba
- [VBA Outlook - Rename attachments and save to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244636/vba-outlook-rename-attachments-and-save-to-folder)