# Macro saves same file with different names instead of each file

Tags: vba, outlook

So, I have a macro that creates a directory, renames the attachment and saves it running on a rule as messages come into outlook.  The problem is if 3 emails come in with addresses of

> 123 main st, city 1
>   456 main st, city 2
>   789 main st city 3

It will save them in the appropriate folders, and it will name the file appropriately based on the address, but when you go into the files, all of them have the same information, so it is saving the attachment for the address of `456 main st` as all 3 file names.

Here is my code:

```
Private Function CreateDir(FldrPath As String)
    Dim Elm As Variant
    Dim CheckPath As String

    CheckPath = ""
    For Each Elm In Split(FldrPath, "\")
        CheckPath = CheckPath & Elm & "\"

        If Len(Dir(CheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir CheckPath
            Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Created"
        End If

        Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Exist"
    Next
End Function

Sub SaveEagleView(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strSubject As String, strExt As String
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim NextFriday As Date
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim varAddress As Variant
    Dim City As Variant
    Dim fdObj As Object
    Dim JobArea As String
    Dim JobCity As Variant
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFinalPath As String
    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Dim sFileExt As String

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim enviro As String
    NextFriday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday)
    Set myfolder = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Loop through emails in folder
    For i = 1 To myfolder.Items.Count
        Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)
        msgtext = myitem.Body

        'Search for Specific Text
        delimitedMessage = Right$(msgtext, Len(msgtext) - InStr(1, msgtext, "Address: ") - 8)
        varAddress = Split(delimitedMessage, ",")

        'Assign the job address from email to variable
        sFileName = varAddress(0)
        JobCity = RTrim(LTrim(varAddress(1)))


        'Define office area based on job city

        If JobCity = "Panama City" Or JobCity = "Mexico Beach" Or JobCity = "Panama City Beach" Or JobCity = "Lynn Haven" Or JobCity = "Port Saint Joe" Then
            JobArea = "Panama"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Daytona Beach" Or JobCity = "Port Orange" Or JobCity = "Deltona" Or JobCity = "Ormond Beach" Or JobCity = "Deland" Then
            JobArea = "Daytona"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Orlando" Then
            JobArea = "Orlando"
        ElseIf JobCity = "Jacksonville" Or JobCity = "Jacksonville Beach" Then
            JobArea = "Jacksonville"
        Else
            JobArea = JobCity
        End If

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            saveFolder = "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\EagleView\" & Format$(NextFriday, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "\" & JobArea & "\"

            CreateDir saveFolder
            If Right(objAtt.FileName, 3) = "PDF" Then
                sFileExt = ".pdf"
                File = saveFolder & sFileName & sFileExt
                objAtt.SaveAsFile File
            End If

            '            With objMsg
            '               .To = "Careers@Email.com"
            '              .CC = "CustomerService@Email.com"
            '             .Subject = "New EagleView Needs Uploaded"
            '            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            '           .Body = "A new EagleView has been received for the " & JobArea & " office. The file name is " & sFileName & " and needs to be uploaded. Thanks!"
            '          .Send
            '     End With

            '    Set objMsg = Nothing

        Next
    Next

    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code to create the email is commented out because it's not working, but I'd rather make sure the file saving is working correctly before moving forward with trying to get that working.

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Edited to provide more info:

So, the emails will have this in the body:

> • Address: 123 main St, City, State 12345-1234

The way the code is written should, and seems to, it should loop through the emails the rule applies to, and extract the street address and apply that value to the `sFileName`, and this part works properly as it loops through, and gets the correct file name for each email that comes through; however, it is just applying that name to the same file over and over again.

The rule that runs says

> Apply this rule after the message arrives
>      from admin@email.com
>      and with EagleView in the subject
>      and with $ in the body
>      and on this computer only
>   move it to
>   and run `Project1.SaveEagleView`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code or inserted a breakpoint to try to see what's going on?

Comment: I did originally; however, Monday night there was a power outage here, and since then, it has not been working.  Since I am a complete novice in VBA, I am wondering if maybe there is an issue with the placement of the `next` for the first `For` statement.

Edit for mor info:
When my computer came back up, I had to reset it, and I rewrote this rule by copying and pasting my code from a previous question, and implementing a solution given to me on that question.  I had to modify the fix a little bit because it kept telling me `subscript out of range` for the `JobCity=varAddress(1)` line.

Comment: What is the value of `sFileName` for these attachments? Looks like it will be the same.

Comment: Your _office area_ part of the code could be written using a [Select....Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) statement which would make it easier to read and add to.

Comment: @SJR Added more details to help answer.
@DarrenBartrup-Cook I will look into that in the future, but for now, I am going to stick with what I have just because I know how `if` statements work; thank you for the info!

Comment: I _think_ this is a missing `Option Explicit` problem.   Your attachments are `itm.Attachments` but you `Set myitem = myfolder.Items(i)` and `itm` isn't defined anywhere.  Without `Option Explicit` it just creates the variable as needed - with `Option Explicit` it would've shouted "where's that variable come from?"  **Scratch that maybe** - it's passed as an argument.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook would that be the case for the code here:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244636/vba-outlook-rename-attachments-and-save-to-folder  

that is where I got this code, and I just adapted it to fit my needs.

Comment: No, I can't see a problem with that code.

Comment: Ok, that confuses me more then since I'm not sure how using `itm` in my code the same way it's used in that code causes an issue in mine, but not the other.  Both have `itm As Outlook.MailItem` and then have `For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments`.  Can you explain how it causes a problem in mine and not in the one I adapted?  I'm guessing my limited knowledge doesn't allow me to understand how my adapting that code changed what needed to be done.

Comment: I'll try - `itm` is an email that is passed to the `SaveEagleView` procedure.  I'm guessing it's passed as part of a `ItemAdd` event (a procedure watching certain folders for any emails to be added to it).  You also have `myitem` which appears to pull each email from the currently selected folder.  You seem to pull `JobCity` from the `myitem` emails.  The attachments are taken from `itm`.  I guess I don't see where the two emails match up - one that is passed to the procedure, and the one(s) taken from the selected folder.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're saying, a fix would be for me to find a way to rewrite my `For` statements so both the JobCity and attachments are pulling from the same email

Comment: I think so - hard to tell without seeing the emails.  I take it the attachments and address text are in the same email (in which case yes - pull both from same email).  How is `itm` passed to the procedure?  Also - if use @Darren in your text I'll get a notification when you comment back. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, the address text and the attachment are in the same email.  I have a rule setup to recognize when these emails come in, move it to the appropriate folder for that vendor, print the email body (this will be the next step in this process is to save the email body, but it's more important to save the attachments at this juncture), and then it runs this macro to rename and save the attachment.  Eventually this macro will send an email to notify the person who needs to upload the attachments to our CRM that there is a new one.  Hopefully this answers how `itm` is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, it's a cut-down version so all it's doing is saving the file, and I'm assuming the email is being passed to the procedure correctly.

The first problem I can see is if an email contains more than one PDF attachment - it will save both in the same folder with same name (so the first will get overwritten).

```
Sub SaveEagleView(itm As MailItem)

    Const SAVE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\EagleView\"

    Dim msgText As String
    Dim delimitedMessage As String
    Dim varAddress As Variant
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim JobCity As String
    Dim JobArea As String
    Dim objAtt As Attachment
    Dim NextFriday As String
    Dim Save_Folder As String

    NextFriday = Format(Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday), "yyyy-mm-dd")

    msgText = itm.Body
    delimitedMessage = Right$(msgText, Len(msgText) - InStr(1, msgText, "Address: ") - 8)
    varAddress = Split(delimitedMessage, ",")
    sFileName = varAddress(0)
    JobCity = Trim(varAddress(1)) 'TRIM does both LTRIM & RTRIM.

    Select Case JobCity
        Case "Panama City", "Mexico Beach", "Panama City Beach", "Lynn Haven", "Port Saint Joe"
            JobArea = "Panama"
        Case "Daytona Beach", "Port Orange", "Deltona", "Ormand Beach", "Deland"
            JobArea = "Daytona"
        Case "Jacksonville", "Jacksonville Beach"
            JobArea = "Jacksonville"
        Case Else
            JobArea = JobCity 'Orlando would fall in here to.
    End Select

    Save_Folder = SAVE_PATH & NextFriday & "\" & JobArea & "\"
    If Len(Dir(Save_Folder)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Save_Folder
    End If

    If itm.Attachments > 0 Then
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            If GetExt(objAtt.FileName) = "PDF" Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile Save_Folder & sFileName & ".pdf"
            End If
        Next objAtt
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetExt(FileName As String) As String
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetExt = oFSO.GetExtensionName(FileName)
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

**Also very important -**

- Select `Tools` ~ `Options`
- In the `Editor` tab check `Require Variable Declaration`.

This will place `Option Explicit` at the top of each new module and force you to declare each variable before use.

You had 6 non-declared variables in your code.  Misspelling a variable would cause a new one to be created and the old one to retain an old or no value - causing mayhem further down the line possibly with no error message.

**Edit:**
I'm not sure how you're getting the script to run with a rule as it has an argument passed to it.
The way I would do it is to watch a folder and run the script whenever an email is moved to that folder (either manually moved or by a rule).

Add this code to `ThisOutlookSession` and it will call the `SaveEagleView` procedure, passing it the email that was moved to the folder.
You may have to change `MailItem` in the `SaveEagleView` procedure name to `Object`.
The first line must be at the very top of the module - before any procedures.

```
Dim WithEvents EagleView As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Rename to correct account/folder.
    With ns.Folders.Item("EagleView").Folders.Item("Inbox")
        Set EagleView = .Folders.Item("EagleView").Items
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub EagleView_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    SaveEagleView Item
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()

    Set EagleView = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This does not seem to be working entirely.  It doesn't save the items.  It creates the folder path; however, nothing is getting saved.  I did add the Orlando one to the `select case` because there are other cities that will fall under that area office.  The `JobArea = JobCity` is meant as a catch for any cities that have not yet been assigned to an area office.

Comment: Check this line:  `objAtt.SaveAsFile Save_Folder & sFileName & ".pdf"`.  Also in the `Locals` window (`View` ~ `Locals`) check that the `objAtt` variable is actually holding a reference to a PDF file.  In the `Immediate` window type `?Save_Folder & sFileName & ".pdf"` and check that it returns a valid file path & name.

Comment: Typing `?Save_Folder & sFileName & ".pdf"` only returns `.pdf` Nothing shows in the `Locals` window.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said put a breakpoint on that line by clicking in the left border. The code will pause there, then do it

Comment: When I press `F5` to run it, it just brings up the Macros box with none of my macros listed.  Also, after doing the breakpoint, it still only returns `.pdf` and nothing shows in the Locals window.

Comment: `F5` won't run it as it needs to have `itm` sent to it.  In Outlook I generally find it easier to actually fire the event by sending an email.  Did the breakpoint definitely go in - the line of code should have been highlighted with a dark red (brown?) colour when you click in the border, when executed the code will stop on that line which will then be highlighted in yellow - [Debugging VBA Code: Adding Breakpoints](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/4/8/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints)

Comment: Ok, when an email comes in and runs the script, I get a `Run-time error 5` `Invalid procedure call or argument` and it highlights `If itm.Attachments  > 0 Then`and `objAtt` value is `Nothing` in the `Locals` window.

Comment: That sounds like `itm` isn't an email so it's can't find the attachment.  Could you post (in your original question) the code that calls the `SaveEagleView` procedure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, the `SaveEagleView` procedure is run as part of a `run script` in a rule I have created.  If you'd like, I can post the rule conditions that filter out the emails the rule applies to and what the rule does.

Comment: Yes please - I've not run a script from a rule before.  I usually add a rule to move an email to a particular folder and then use an event to watch that folder.  Could you post the script it runs as well?

Comment: Ok, I added that info, hopefully it will help.

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  In rules when I select _run a script_ the only procedures it will let me choose from are ones that have no arguments to pass - so I could select the `Sub Test1()` procedure, but not `Sub Test(itm As MailItem)` procedure.  How did you get it to allow `SaveEagleView`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  I don't remember, but I think what I did was wrote what I thought would work, and then when it didn't I edited the macro while it was still saved to the rule.